# why we are not using semicolon after header files

Tags: c++

I am just curious why we are not using a semicolon after the header file as we write it as :
`#include<iostream>`
and not as
`#include<iostream>;`

Comment: Because it's a preprocessor directive and preprocessor directives don't require semicolons: they're processed prior to compilation.

Comment: It is just a syntax rule. Preprocessors don't need to have a semicolon at the end.

Comment: #include is a directive for the preprocessor, the compiler never sees it.  An end-of-line character terminates preprocessing directives, a backslash is required to extend a directive across multiple lines.  Semicolon terminates a statement, the compiler's parser pays attention to it.  Why there's a distinction is hard to reverse-engineer after 50 years, might have something to do with existing text processing tools that AT&T had available back then.  Or the common desire to use ; in macro definitions and not make it special.

Comment: Dennis Ritchie about it: "The preprocessor was originally considered an optional adjunct to the language itself. Indeed, for some years, it was not even invoked unless the source program contained a special signal at its beginning. This attitude persisted, and explains both the incomplete integration of the syntax of the preprocessor with the rest of the language and the imprecision of its description in early reference manuals. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are  preprocessor. The preprocessor provides the ability for the inclusion of header files, macro expansions, conditional compilation, and line control.
They don't need a semicolon.

The preprocessor replaces the line

```
#include <someFile>
```

with the text of the file 'someFile.h', which declares some functions, classes,...